# Getting react-native to work on android

Tags: android, react-native

How exactly do you get react-native-cli to work on android (Windows Computer). I did the npm install but it says 'bash command react-native not found' every time.  I also tried to modify the path, I used which react-native on try and check the problem and it's still not found.

Comment: On the requirements list the first one is "OS X - Only OS X is currently supported" https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

react-native does not officially support windows as a host platform yet. Although there are people that have attempted to make it run and some of the succeeded: https://gist.github.com/mqli/e1e6576e9838d885a43a
There are also pull-requests coming for windows support so it's very likely that windows support will land in master soon.